# default not null generic value

Tags: c#, generics

I'am trying to create a generic class that contains a list of generic type
but i want to have a default value other than null to check if an item been deleted
the list should look like this

```
0 TypeV   (some value of TypeV)
1 null
2 null    (never been used)
3 default (deleted)
4 TypeV
```

any ideas ?

Comment: I could not parse "to check if an item been deleted
the list should look like this"

Comment: mmm i mean if i have a normal array of some type (string) all the items in the array is set to null, if i added an item then delete it later how to know that there where an item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference type default value will be `null` (you can't define if value was never used, or it was deleted). So your idea will not work for generic parameters of reference type. On the other hand you can't have null values for non-reference types. So, *the only option is an array of objects* (it can hold both nulls and value types):

```
// TODO: check for index fit array range
public class Foo<T>
   where T : struct
{
   object[] values = new object[5];

   public void Add(T value, int index)
   {
       // TODO: do not allow to add default values to array
       values[index] = value;
   }

   public void Delete(int index)
   {
       values[index] = default(T);
   }
}
```

And

```
Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>();
foo.Add(1, 0);
foo.Add(2, 3);
foo.Add(3, 4);
foo.Delete(3);
```

At this point `values` will be:

```
0 1       (some value of T)
1 null    (never been used)
2 null    (never been used)
3 default (deleted)
4 3
```

But anyway you can't define if some item was deleted, or it was added with default value.. So, your idea will work if you never add default values to array.

Comment: but what is the point of having generics if we are going to use objects

Comment: @user1748906 same question I want to ask you - see your sample and my explanation why only object fits your needs

Comment: i guess you are right, and your solution works even with reference types if i have a static readonly field DEFAULT = new object();

Answer (score 4):

If `TypeV` is not under your control then it can always be a value type, in which case there is absolutely no value that can be used as a sentinel (for reference types, you can have a sentinel value and use `object.ReferenceEquals` to check if a slot contains it). Which means that the only possible implementation is to use one additional bit of information per slot in the list.

A reasonable choice would be to keep a `List<Tuple<TypeV, bool>>` and use the `bool` as a "deleted" flag.

Comment: I agree. Isn't this case why `Nullable<T>` was introduced?

Comment: @neontapir: No, not really. What if `TypeV` is `Nullable<Something>`?

Comment: @Jon He's not saying that you should use `Nullable` as your implementation, he's referring to the fact that `Nullable` contains both the value and a boolean indication if it's "real", and you're using the same model.

Answer (score -2):

It is better to use dictionary then

```
List<Tuple<TypeV, bool>>
```

because you can get the status in O(1).

or just use HashSet and when you want to check if item is deleted use Contains(item). this also work at O(1).

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: You could have a `Dictionary<int, TValue>` to represent a sparsely populated list, although this answer doesn't actually say that or provide enough information to really be an "answer".